# I need Help Making my VB 2008 Express Web Browser

Tags: vb.net, browser, window, tabbed

Every time I click on a link it opens in Internet Explorer but I want it to open in another window of my web browser.

Details: 
I created a tabbed web browser which is using a tab control. Other Controls would be a normal web browser.

Comment: This should e re-tagged to vb.net

Answer (score 0):

You have to hookup the newwindow2 of the (old activex) browser control event like this:

```
Private Sub AxWebBrowser1_NewWindow2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow2Event) Handles AxWebBrowser1.NewWindow2
    Dim frmWB As Form1
    frmWB = New Form1()

    frmWB.AxWebBrowser1.RegisterAsBrowser = True
    e.ppDisp = frmWB.AxWebBrowser1.Application
    frmWB.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Details can be found here http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B311282&x=8&y=21